# Meteor run android-device in development mode

Tags: android, meteor

When I run the following command `meteor run android-device` I app loads on the device, but I cannot login or perform any action, and I get the following error message :

`I20160125-16:26:04.688(2) (android:http://meteor.local/:0) XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.20.41:3000/sockjs/info?cb=pp4d6iodxu. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://meteor.local' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.`

My phone is in developer mode, and I'm debugging (or attempting to) via USB.

As I already mentioned, the app is loading, but I'm dead from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a number of things, including setting up another demo app, multiple restarts, setting up browser policies and tons of access Rules etc, it finally began to work.  The things I tried:

- plenty of accessRules in the mobile config
- Browser Policy Package with standard rules
- temporarily setting environmental variables for root url etc.

So in order to figure out what specifically caused the issue I began to work backwards removing things, until I removed ALL OF IT.  and then it still worked.

I have tried for two weeks to replicate the issue now, and everything is working smoothly.  Putting this down to a random bug, in my system, there are definitely more than a few people that have hit it.

The only thing I think I could have missed is a package update, that patched some package in the dependency tree that caused the whole thing to bomb on mobile.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `App.accessRule("*");` to /mobile-config.js

Comment: I believe this to be only part of the problem.   I have got it working, but need to trim down a few of the possibly extraneous bits I've added to see what the final recipe for this particularly annoying situation is.